# Slick Slider Variable width menu and click issue after items end

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, react-slick

Slick slider with variable width items and arrow on the right scrolls even after the last item reached end. Anyway to fix this?

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/60hy4j3z/  (Click on the right arrow continuously and you could see the issue).

```
$('.variable-width').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: false,
    variableWidth: true
  });
```

Also if possible I would like to hide the right arrow if item count is less than the width.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with react-slicк. the problem there was that all the other slides except the first were set as style(pointer-events: none) that's because you set slidesToShow: 1.

The solution:
override styles that turn off the pointer-event. In the case of react-slick I did it like this

```
:global .slick-slide:not(.slick-active) {
    pointer-events: all !important;
}
```